# Ajax - disabling input until response received

Tags: ajax

should input buttons that submit ajax requests be disabled after a request is made untl the response is received.

Im thinking specifically adding products to a shopping basket using a button.

Im trying to make the process as bullit proof as possible but a quite new to using ajax so dont know the best practices on these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that is a great practice.  But, it would also help to give the user a "processing" (or some other phrase) notice while you've disabled the button.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling input is a very useful UI element to prevent the user from doing something bad, but I would caution against relying on it too much.

You should probably also do some server side checking to make sure you aren't receiving a duplicate request. This will shield you from browser bugs/non js-browsers etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it as bullet proof as possible, then you need to show an animation right before you kick off the AJAX request, and handle both success and failure of that request.

As far as preventing an additional request, that depends on your specific action.  In your case, updating a cart, it could go both ways.  If I "click to add item to cart" once, but there are other items on the page that I could also add to my cart, let me click on the other "Add to Cart" button...right?